# Decimal Hour into Time?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an hour field in a database like 1.4, 1.5, 1.7 that I need to convert back to HH:MM. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: What is 1.4 supposed to represent?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`TimeSpan.FromHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromhours.aspx):

```
double value;
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromHours(value);
```

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.FromHours(1.4)); // prints 01:24:00 to the console.
```

Answer (score 1):

The HH (hour) figure is the number before the decimal.

To get the minutes figure, subtract the whole number portion so you only have the amount after the decimal, then multiply the fraction by 60 to get the minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the **TimeSpan** approach in the accepted answer was good for hours < 24 (1 day).

A **DateTime** approach suited my need to handle > 24 hour times without having days (and not have a leading 0):

```
    public string DecHrsToHHMM(double dHours)
    {
        DateTime dTime = new DateTime().AddHours(dHours);
        return dTime.ToString("H:mm");
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Convert.ToDateTime(float)
```

Comment: I didn't mark this down, but this throws an InvalidCastException