# Convert Decimal (62.25) to Hours and Minutes String (62 Hours and 15 Minutes)?

Tags: c#, datetime, decimal, data-conversion

Is there a simple way to convert my Decimal value (ex. 62.25) to a returned string like "62 Hours : 15 Minutes"? I have been looking at several posts similar to this one ([Decimal Hour into Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087699/decimal-hour-into-time)), but even the suggestions that say they work for figures greater than 24hr periods are not working.

Comment: How hard could it be to separate the `25` and multiply that by 0.6?

Comment: This isn't really a `datetime` operation, despite being in hours. Just think of it as any other numeric value that you need to convert to different units.

Comment: Use Math.Truncate to get the whole integer part of your double. You can use modulo 24 to get the remainder after removing all parts divisible by 24 producing your hour component. You can get the decimal part by subtracting the value from Math.Truncate earlier from the initial double value. You can then normalize this value (which will between 0.0 and 0.99999) into the range 1-60 to get the minutes.

Comment: You could use `TimeSpan.FromHours`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pretty simple:

```js
var decimal = 62.25;

var hours = Math.floor(decimal);
var mins = 60 * (decimal - hours);

console.log(`${hours} hours, ${mins} minutes`);
```

In c#, you can likely just leverage the `TimeSpan` class. See [.NET fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0pWqyo):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dec = 62.25m;
        var ts = TimeSpan.FromHours((double)dec);

        Console.WriteLine("{0} Hours, {1} Minutes", Math.Floor(ts.TotalHours), ts.Minutes);
    }
}
```

Comment: 62 hours 15 minutes

Comment: Yes, but trying to convert to Hours and Mins, not seconds. Can be anything from 0.5 to 520 as a decimal and then need represented purely as Hours : Minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This question is really simple and this answer too and has a lot of basic programming on it and there are a lot of different ways of doing it. The simple one is to use cast:

```
double date = getDate(); //62.25. I don't know where you get date from :P
int hours = (int)date; //62
float minutes = 60* (date - hours); //60 * (62.25 - 62 ) = 15

Write( "Hours: " + hours + "\nMinutes: " + minutes );
```

Consider doing valdiations if minutes have decimal points (12.3 minutes should be rounded, etc.)

Comment: It's never a date value. the Value comes to me as a large decimal representing number of hours worked (something like 0.5 to 520) and want to display as (Total Hours) : (Minutes), nothing to do with days.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic read the code provided before saying that. He is not speaking of any date. All his code does is exactly what you are asking for. if you pass 2568.75 it return the text "Hours: 2568 Minutes: 45"

Comment: I used data types since I saw tag "C#". But in the end it's just the same. I don't used Date type :) It's just decimals

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a try

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine (DecimalToTime(62.25)); // will output 62 Hours:15
}

string DecimalToTime(double dbTime)
{
    int hour = (int)dbTime;
    int minute = (int)((dbTime - hour) * 60);

    string time = hour + " Hours:" + minute;

    return time;

}
```